# GTK prevent custom widget from grabbing focus

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I've implemented a musical keyboard as a subclass of Fixed and where each individual key is a subclass of DrawingArea, and so far, it works great: custom drawing code in expose, press+release functionality working... kind of. See, here's the problem: I want the user to be able to drag the mouse across the keyboard with the mouse down to play it. I currently capture the button press and release signals, as well as enter and leave notify. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work because the widget seems to grab focus of the mouse as soon as the mouse is pressed over it. This makes sense for normal buttons, but not for a musical keyboard. Is there any good way to remedy this other than rewriting the entire keyboard to be one massive DrawingArea?

Also, it shouldn't matter, but in case it does I'm using GTK#.

Comment: Try using EventBox instead of drawing area and see if you get different results. Also don't forget to set CanFocus to true.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [GooCanvas](http://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas): You can represent each of the keys as CanvasPolylines, fill them with the colors you need. Each of the Canvas items is a GtkWidget, so you can act on events like `enter`, `leave`, `button-pressed` etc.

This method seems to make more sense (to me) than separate DrawingAreas. As each drawn element is still accessible, you can even change colors/size and other properties dynamically. Also, Polyline lets you make more complex shapes.